# give information of some files from an xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm new in xml and i want some help. I'm trying to uploading a zip file with 3 photos and an info.xml in my server. This xml will have information about the photos(one title for each photo,one description for each photo,the location of each photo etc). what i've done until here: i'm uploading the zip file(without the xml) and extracting it in a file. But i have no idea how to make that info.xml. From there i have to read the xml and save the information for each photo in my database(according the name of the photo).My question is can anyone give me an example code of how that xml going to be.

Comment: Unless there are some specifications on the server side, I would say you could use actually any format you want for you XML file.

Comment: basicly..i dont know.i'm using wampserver

Comment: What is your question by the way? How the XML could look like? Or how to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a structure for your XML file, if you are the one to decide for it.

```
<photos>
    <photo id="1">
        <name>name for photo 1</name>
        <description>description for photo 1</description>
        <location>location for photo 1</location>
        ...
    </photo>
    <photo id="2">
        <name>name for photo 2</name>
        <description>description for photo 2</description>
        <location>location for photo 2</location>
        ...
    </photo>
    ...
</photos>
```

However, if the XML file has to follow a certain structure as per the server application specifications, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: thanks for the code. i didnt know that the server have specifications of the structure of xml

Comment: ok i've done this. now can you help me on how can i read them and insert them to my database?

Comment: This is a totally different question. You should first try, and then come back here if you face any issue.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you would want to make a file similar to this:

```
<photos>
<photo name="photo1">
here you would write your description.
</photo>
<photo name="photo2">
here you would write your description.
</photo>
</photos>
```

after you upload it you can read the data by using simpleXML in case you are using php.